# Finish Activity - Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity, activity-finish

I'm doing a project with Google Maps for Android. I've created a MapActivity to load some places I've saved on the server. So I have this class

```
public class PlaceItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context mContext = null;
    MapActivity mapAct = null;

    public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapActivity map) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
              this.macAct = map;
    }

    public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
          mContext = context;
        }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }


    @Override
    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();

     this.mapAct.finish();

      return true;
    }
```

Well, when I click at a saved place, the program breaks.

I'm creating the object on the mapActivity:

```
PlaceItemzedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new PlaceItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
```

Can you help me please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: As you've solved it please take the time to share your solution with the community and accept it as the answer. That way anybody hitting the same problem doesn't need to ask the same question over and over. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here //part of your code

```
  @Override
  protected boolean onTap(int index) {
   OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
   AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
   dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
   dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
   dialog.show();//here you show a alert dialog on current activity 

  //this.mapAct.finish();//and here you finish current activity

  return true;
}
```

at this situation application crashes..
and use

```
finish();
```

for your

```
 this.mapAct.finish();
```

Comment: and please post your logcat output with every question for better understanding the question for us

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you are creating your `itemizedoverlay` object using...

```
PlaceItemzedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new PlaceItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
```

...then the following line isn't valid...

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Basically you have two constuctors for `PlaceItemzedOverlay`. The second parameter of one is a `Context` and the other is a `MapActivity`. These are the only two places where either `mContext` or `mapAct` are set to a valid reference and both are mutually exclusive. In other words whichever constructor is used, one or other of `mContext` or `mapAct` will remain `null`.

Mixing your use of `mContext` and `mapAct` in your `onTap` method is never going to work...

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

...

this.mapAct.finish();
```